# Why Golang GORM hooks BeforeUpdate, AfterUpdate not firing?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have tried Golang Gorm Hook from [here](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html), but not firing anything when trying to update the table **md_transaction** through Model **ModTrans**, here my golang code:

```
package models

import (
   "time"
   "fmt"
   "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

type ModTrans struct {
    TRX_ID  string `gorm:"primary_key;column:trx_id" json:"TRX_ID"`
    TRX_CODE string `gorm:"column:trx_code" json:"TRX_CODE"`
    TRX_DATE *time.Time `gorm:"column:trx_date" json:"TRX_DATE"`
    TRX_TYPE string `gorm:"column:trx_type" json:"TRX_TYPE"`
    TRX_PAY_METHOD int `gorm:"column:trx_pay_method" json:"TRX_PAY_METHOD"`
}

func (t *ModTrans) TableName() string {
    return "md_transaction"
}

// Updating data in same transaction
func (t *ModTrans) AfterUpdate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    fmt.Println(">>>>  it's work and firing....")
    return
}
```

based on documentation

> If you have defined specified methods for a model, it will be called automatically

I'm new in hooks golang GORM, why that hooks not firing well? Are there other examples out there? I have tried to search on Google did not find, maybe my keywords search are not quite right.

Comment: Make sure to pass a `*ModTrans` instance to the gorm update code and not a `ModTrans`.

Comment: @mkopriva gorm updates method I have used, err = DB.Model(models.ModTrans{}).Where(&models.ModTrans{ TRX_CODE: pOrderCode }).Updates(models.ModTrans{TRX_PAY_METHOD: 1, TRX_STATUS: 2}).Error

Comment: You've used a pointer only in the where method, that's insufficient. Pass a pointer to the Updates method. `*ModTrans`=pointer, `ModTrans`=not a pointer. To get the pointer use the address operator `&`.

Comment: @mkopriva nice,,,, >>>>  it's work and firing... just change code all method to pointer,  DB.Model(&models.ModTrans{}).Where(&models.ModTrans{ TRX_CODE: pOrderCode }).Updates(&models.ModTrans{TRX_PAY_METHOD: 1, TRX_STATUS: 2}).Error .. thank's you save my day

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass **model** for hooks to work.

```
DB.Model(&models.ModTrans{}).Where("uuid = (?)", uuid).Update(&modTrans)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's firing well with changing method to pointer with operator & :

```
err = DB.Model(&models.ModTrans{}).Where(&models.ModTrans{ TRX_CODE: pOrderCode }).
    Updates(&models.ModTrans{
        TRX_PAY_METHOD: 1, 
        TRX_STATUS: 2,
    }).Error
```