# How to add default value in gorm from another package

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a struct defined as

```
type User struct {
    Name string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);size:100;not null;default:null;" json:"name"`
    UserTypeId uuid.UUID sql:"type:uuid REFERENCES usertype(id);" gorm:"index;not null;default:null;" json:"user_type_id"`
    Score int gorm:"size:36;index;not null;default:null;" json:"score"`
}
```

Now i want to use some contant defined in another package lets say defaultID = '1234'instead of null as default in UserTypeID how do i mention this constant inside gorm default value also i dont want to put it like this

```
 UserTypeId    sql:"type:uuid REFERENCES usertype(id);" gorm:"index;not null;default:1234;" json:"user_type_id"`
```

Instead of directly mentioning the id i want to take it from a constant defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `BeforeSave` or `BeforeUpdate` hooks. For example:

```
func (u *User) BeforeSave(tx *gorm.DB) error {
  //first, check the UserTypeId value

  //second, update the value
  u.UserTypeId = defaultID
}
```

Comment: I liked the solution but the hook is not firing up can you guide me how to use this i think i am facing this issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436224/why-golang-gorm-hooks-beforeupdate-afterupdate-not-firing)

Comment: What method are you using when saving the records? `Save`, `Create`, `Update`, `Updates`?

Comment: Trying with AutoMigrate

Comment: I want to add a UserTypeID as a new column and then want to set the default id

Comment: I don't think the hooks get triggered with AutoMigrate, this answer doesn't apply to it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Struct tags can't be built from string constants. This is [by design](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4740).

However, you can achieve this using reflect package but not recommended.

Comment: Well in that case maybe i have to make that field null and backfill it because i really want that field to be taken from a constant for better use